# how to disable proximity when AVPlayer stop playing

Tags: ios, avplayer, proximitysensor

In my app i have to record audio and play this audio and add proximity when play this audio near your ear so for this i have to do this code when play button click:

```
- (IBAction)btnPlayPauseTapped:(id)sender {
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    [device setProximityMonitoringEnabled: YES];
    if (device.proximityMonitoringEnabled == YES) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:APP_DELEGATE name:@"UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:APP_DELEGATE selector:@selector(proximityChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification" object:device];
//other code 
    }
```

Notification call this method when proximity enable:

```
- (void) proximityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"proximity changed called");
    UIDevice *device = [notification object];
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    if(device.proximityState == 1){
        [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
        [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:nil];
        [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
    }
    else{
        [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
        [audioSession  overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
        [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

    }
}
```

when player stop playing or pause i add this:

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[device setProximityMonitoringEnabled: NO];
```

but when i again start playing audio and put device near ear that time it called notification method(proximityChanged) and at that time proximity state also get 1 and audio session category also set as playandrecord but it did not play this audio in ear speaker . it play audio in main speaker.

please help me in this.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my problem after 2 days in that when player stop player as I disable proximity is correct but I changed audiosession category in proximitychange method.

```
  - (void) proximityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIDevice *device = [notification object];
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    BOOL success;
     success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    if(device.proximityState == 1){
        NSLog(@"bool %s", success ? "true" : "false");
        [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:nil];
        [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
    }
    else{
         NSLog(@"bool %s", success ? "true" : "false");
        [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
        [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

    }
```